# Getting Wordpress site online with Nginx server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns

I've been beating my head against the wall all day with this. I cannot seem to get my wordpress website online - using nginx. If anyone has any suggestions for getting this setup, it would be greatly appreciated. I have two websites on my nginx server. The first one - not a wordpress site - is active online - mathtutortime.com. The second is a new wordpress site - triadmathtutor.com. I modeled the wordpress server, triadmathtutor.com after the first one that is already working. Here are my two servers in nginx:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/MathTutorTime/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.mathtutortime.com;

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~* \.(php|html|htm)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name; 
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/...aaa
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/...bbb
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #listen 80;# ssl; managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl;# managed by Certbot
}

server {
    root /var/www/html/TriadMathTutor;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.triadmathtutor.com;
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.triadmathtutor.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.triadmathtutor.com.error.log;
    
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    
    location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    }
    
    # SECURITY : Deny all attempts to access PHP Files in the uploads directory
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
    
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    
    location ~* \.(php|html|htm)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name; 
        include fastcgi_params;
    }`
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/...xxx
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/...zzz
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    listen 443 ssl;# managed by Certbot
}
```

My issue is that when I try to connect to my wordpress outside of my home connection, I get that the site cannot be reached. My dns server seems to connect to it sometimes, and then once I think everything is fixed, it disconnects. When I ping my wordpress website from my home network it is trying to ping the loopback address, which confirms the dns is not connecting. The problem is that I don't know why it isn't connecting, or why it is iffy. In wordpress wp_config I have:

```
// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'triadmathtutor' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'rickster26ter' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

I don't know if localhost is an ok location for the db host if it is online, or if it needs to be my domain name...
And in my wordpress admin file I have

```
WordPress Address (URL) 
https://www.triadmathtutor.com
Site Address (URL)  
https://www.triadmathtutor.com
```

so it connects ok locally, but not online - I can't even ping it. Previously I have had user-errors with my dns, but the username password/connected domain is correct this time.

As a final `Strange` thing I am seeing in my log sometimes it seems as if it is trying to connect to my first site - mathtutortime.com, when the second site, triadmathtutor.com is requested:

`2023/08/14 21:07:12 [error] 109467#109467: *2 "/var/www/html/MathTutorTime/html/wp-admin/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.mathtutortime.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.triadmathtutor.com"`

I'm not sure why if I laid out in my server blocks two distinct server_names that should correspond to the domains.

I'm at a loss in general, and am regretting getting wordpress more and more as time goes on. If any wordpress experts out there, I would love some advice.

thank you,

I have tried removing ssl, but that did not fix anything. I cannot get access to triadmathtutor.com correctly outside of my home network.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please ask in ServerFault.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.